# Efficient Pandas Vectorisation for nested loops problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, nested-loops

```
s=[]
for idx2,source in df.iterrows():
  num_flux=len(df[df['flux_radio']>source['flux_match']])
  surface_density=num_flux/area
  s.append(1-np.exp(-1*np.pi*source['Separation']**2*surface_density))

df['s']=s
```

I am trying to convert this for loop into a vectorisation. The dataframe looks like this.

|  | flux_match | Separation | flux_radio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 5000 | 22.2999 | 2.0229 | 11.8 |
| 5001 | 33.2999 | 3.3546 | 22.3 |
| 5002 | 44.2999 | 4.08002 | 13.7 |
| 5003 | 17.4001 | 3.4419 | 13.6 |
| 5004 | 53.7999 | 4.3195 | 18.9 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

For every 'flux_match' we are trying to find how many 'flux_radio' are greater and calculate a statistic with that.

I have used:

```
def func(radio, match, distance, area=6228*5940):

  num_flux = len(radio > match)
  print(num_flux)
  surface_density= num_flux/area
  s= 1-np.exp(-1*np.pi*distance**2*surface_density)
  return s

df['s']= func(
          df['flux_radio'].values, 
          df['flux_match'].values, 
          df['Separation'].values
          )
```

But this gives the wrong values as it calculates 'num_flux' only once.
We want to find 'num_flux' for each 'flux_match'.
Any suggestions for faster ways of doing this would be appreciated as the data being used is large.

Comment: You need to use `df.apply()` here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:
Since you need to compare every `flux_match` to all `flux_radio`, let's first assign each row a complete set of all `flux_radio`. And then `df.explode` to unroll the `dataframe` for later operations:

The data

```
data = np.array([[22.2999, 2.0229, 11.8],
[33.2999, 3.3546, 22.3],
[44.2999, 4.08002, 13.7],
[17.4001, 3.4419, 13.6],
[53.7999,4.3195,18.9]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['flux_match', 'Separation', 'flux_radio'])

area = 6228*5940
```

The result given by your code

```
    flux_match  Separation  flux_radio  s
0   22.2999 2.02290 11.8    3.475070e-07
1   33.2999 3.35460 22.3    0.000000e+00
2   44.2999 4.08002 13.7    0.000000e+00
3   17.4001 3.44190 13.6    2.012060e-06
4   53.7999 4.31950 18.9    0.000000e+00
```

My workaround:

```
# Assign each row a complete collection of 'flux_radio'
df["all_flux_radio"] =  np.tile(df['flux_radio'].to_numpy(), (df.shape[0],1)).tolist()

df_exp = df.explode('all_flux_radio')

df_exp['indicator'] = df_exp['all_flux_radio'] > df_exp['flux_match']

# Compute density
s = df_exp.groupby('flux_match').agg(surface_density=("indicator", "sum")) /area

# Merge density back to the df
df = pd.concat([df.set_index('flux_match'), s], axis=1)

df['s'] = 1 - np.exp(-1*np.pi*df['Separation']**2*df['surface_density'])

# Clean up helper columns
df.reset_index().drop(columns=["all_flux_radio", "surface_density"])
```

This code gives me the identical result as your first code snippet in terms of `s`. Like follows

```
  flux_match    Separation  flux_radio  s
0   17.4001 3.44190 13.6    2.012060e-06
1   22.2999 2.02290 11.8    3.475070e-07
2   33.2999 3.35460 22.3    0.000000e+00
3   44.2999 4.08002 13.7    0.000000e+00
4   53.7999 4.31950 18.9    0.000000e+00
```